# Run the select statement using querystring parameter and fill the custom form with data set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using VS2012 with SQLServer 2008R2 (asp.net). I have a search form to look up by name, this returns the Id of the name. This ID is passed on to the custom form. This form is supposed to run the select statement with the querystring parameter and the fill the form with the dataset. Do I have to run the select query in the page load event?

Answer (score 0):

yes, on page load put

```
if (  Page.IsPostBack == false ) 
BindData ()
```